# How can I incorporate OpenGraph and Twitter Cards into a 2sxc details template in c# razor?

Tags: c#, razor, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a listing and details view in a 2sxc app. In the details view, there's lots of content because it's sort of like an article.

I want to put in an OpenGraph and Twitter Cards into the template so that each unique URL in my app has unique content for each article. How can I set up my C# razor template in 2sxc for OpenGraph and Twitter Cards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the docs from Jeremy, I put this into my C# razor template:

```
@using ToSic.Razor.Blade;

HtmlPage.AddOpenGraph("title", @Content.Name); 
HtmlPage.AddOpenGraph("type", "article");
HtmlPage.AddOpenGraph("url", @Dnn.Tab.FullUrl + "/career/" + Content.urlkey);
HtmlPage.AddOpenGraph("description", "need to determine description somehow");
HtmlPage.AddOpenGraph("image", "https://" + @Dnn.Portal.PortalAlias.HTTPAlias.Replace("/en-ca","").Replace("/fr-ca","") + @Content.Image + "?mode=crop&h=601&w=589&anchor=middlecenter");
```

This worked for both OpenGraph and TwitterCards.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to code those things as-needed. One big helper we've used recently for the OpenGraph stuff is RazorBlade.

[Razor Blade Tutorials](https://2sxc.org/dnn-tutorials/en/razor/blade/home)

[Razor Blade home](https://razor-blade.net/)